# SVG filters after cloning SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, clone, svg-filters

im Trying to work with SVG in browser. and have next Problem!
i use jquery clone() on some svg element.
then append it to window.
then try to delete clone element.

example code

```
 window.makeClone = function (){
     var cloneSVG = $('svg').clone();
     cloneSVG.appendTo('body');
 }
 window.removeClone = function (){
     $('svg:last').remove();
 }
```

and then happened something mystic. i use filter. and after second clone->delete the main svg loss his filter. there is a simple example :http://jsfiddle.net/4vK47/1/

dont know how to fix this (

Comment: its not a correct. see nexts answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what causes this, but part of the problem is probably that after the clone, you have two #f1's. It might work better to define the filter in a single `<svg>` that you never clone, and have the cloned `<svg>` just reference that.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height=0px width=0px id="defs">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height=100px width=100px id="rect">
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"
  fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

See [this update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vK47/2/).

Comment: Thanks, Russell! dont know about saving defs children in a special svg element. i thought that each svg must have own defs with filters. Sorry again, cant vote up because of low reputation. I think it must help me a lot!

Comment: 10 years later, but Russell's solution is still actual! I spend few hours trying to solve it, unitl I found this comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the ID on the `<filter>` and update the filter on the `rect`.

```
window.makeClone = function (){    
    var cloneSVG = $('svg').clone(true);
    cloneSVG
        .find("filter")
            .attr("id", "f" + n)
            .end()
        .find("rect")
            .attr("filter", "url(#f" + n + ")")
            .end()
        .appendTo('body');
    n++;
}
window.removeClone = function (){
    $('svg:last').remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2Wjb/

Comment: Thanks a lot, yea, really the problem was with Ids of elements. cant Vote Up because of low reputation, sorry.

Comment: +1 to U because i use this metod to collect all defs children in own svg.