# SVG background only works in IE

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, svg

I'm trying to put a radialGradient background in a SVG circle and nothing will work. It only works in Internet Explorer. Even just a solid color background won't work. I must have setup my document incorrectly. Maybe this is due to cloning from a hidden copy? The actual project can be seen [here](https://github.com/davidsarver/formulade/tree/ce174b272679d44c1ccf11a256d661fe00ab7338). I have it hosted [here](http://sarverd.com/formulade). To see the problem circle click "New Player". I'm trying now in HTML5, but I believe that I've also had this problem in xhtml.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 225 140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
            id="d00" class="svg">
            <defs>
                <radialGradient cx="20%" cy="20%" id="gearShift">
                    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:white;"/>
                    <stop offset="80%" style="stop-color:black;"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
                    .gear {
                        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 20%, white 20%, black 80%);
                    }
                ]]></style>
            </defs>
            <circle id="gear00" class="gear" cx="70" cy="20" r="10" style="stroke:black;" fill="url(#gearShift)" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.gear{
    stroke:black;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 20%, white 20%, black 80%);
    background-color:red;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(red), to(#f06d06));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);   
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
}
```

I've commented out the following rule in styles.css which shows the Player 0 that all the other players are copied from. This allows the background of the circle to be shown. Once you've added Player 1 when switching between players, whenever Player 0 is hidden, the background on all copies of this circle are hidden.

```
#_00, #sort00, #playertab00, .hidden {
    /*display:none !important;*/
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to set a radial background why does your CSS contain linear-gradient functions?

Comment: Because I was trying everything. Can't even get solid red to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042282/svg-filters-after-cloning-svg). It seems like the issue stems from the fact that the background in the defs section is linked to the circle by an ID. I was cloning it and creating multiple radialGradients with the same ID.

I've fixed this by splitting the def into its own svg element.

```
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgDefs" class="svgDefs">
        <defs>
            <radialGradient cx="35%" cy="35%" id="gearShift">
                <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:white;stop-opacity:1"/>
                <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:black;"/>
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 225 140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
        id="d00" class="svg">
        <circle id="gear00" class="gear" fill="url(#gearShift)" cx="70" cy="20" r="10" style="stroke:black;"/>
    </svg>
</body>
```